# How to redefine object method in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, inheritance, extend, overloading

I would like to overload method of a plugin.

This is the plugin that I use.
http://www.owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js

The library contains the following method:

```
 updateControls : function () {
            var base = this;
            base.updatePagination();
            base.checkNavigation();
            if (base.owlControls) {
                if (base.options.items >= base.itemsAmount) {
                    base.owlControls.hide();
                } else {
                    base.owlControls.show();
                }
            }
        },
```

This is my script for method overloading:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $.fn.owlCarousel = $.extend($.fn.owlCarousel, {
                updateControls:function()
                {
                    console.log("!!");
                    var base = this;
                    base.updatePagination();
                    base.checkNavigation();
                    if (base.owlControls) {
                        base.owlControls.show();
                        base.owlControls.show();
                    }
                }
            });
        })
```

`console.log("!!");` does not appear to be called - what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, it would appear that the initializer for `owlCarousel` does not accept options to override the `updateControls` internal function. You may need to modify the library to accept (and use) an override for the `updateControls` function.

An example of such an edit would be modifying the `init` function in the library, although I'd recommend making use of the `options` object in order to override the function.

```
var Carousel = {
    init : function (options, el) {
        var base = this;

        base.$elem = $(el);
        base.options = $.extend({}, $.fn.owlCarousel.options, base.$elem.data(), options);

        base.userOptions = options;

        // check for override in options of updateControls function
        if (typeof base.userOptions.updateControls == "function") base.updateControls = base.userOptions.updateControls;

        base.loadContent();
    }
```

This modified `init` function would allow you to specify the `updateControls` function, as you have done in your second code sample.